# SQL - exact decimal value from averaging a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried reading up on previously asked questions, and trying different solutions but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am still learning so any tips and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Here is my query

```
select  AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy)) AS DayDiff

FROM database1.dbo.table1

where month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
```

Result sql gives me is 9, but when I average it in excel it is 9.18. I need sql to give me 2 decimal places. I tried using 'cast' but I cant figure out the correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server does decimal division, even for averages.  I just multiply by 1.0 as a quick fix:

```
select  AVG(1.0 * DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy)) AS DayDiff
```

Comment: You can use `1e` to get binary floating-point calculations. This is not normally what you want (decimal floating-point tends to be more accurate, or at least less surprising) but the question specifically mentioned Excel, and Excel uses binary floating-point, so in cases where it's important that the results match this needs to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

`DATEDIFF` function returns integer (`INT`) values. Average (`AVG`) returns the same data type as the expression that holds inside. Operations between integer values (in SQL Server) return integer values. However, operations between integer and other numeric values (like float or decimal) return the last one.

So if you convert the `DATEDIFF` to return decimal, the result will be decimal.

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy))) AS DayDiff
```

Following the same rule, a hard-coded value of `1.0` represents a decimal, so multiplying any integer value with `1.0` yields the same value but with decimal data type.

```
SELECT  AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) * 1.0) AS DayDiff
```

As Jeroen mentioned, converting the argument will yield a decimal average, but with more than 2 decimals. You will have to convert the average result at the end.

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), 
        AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) * 1.0)) AS DayDiff
```

Comment: You need an additional `CONVERT` on the end result if you want two decimal places. Converting the argument is not enough in itself, due to the way precision and scale end up when combining operands.